# Android Oreo autofill on chrome

Tags: chrome-for-android, 8.1-oreo, auto-fill

I know android Oreo has an auto fill feature, and I like that it can be integrated with a third party password manager. However what is unclear is whether that auto fill feature works within a browser like chrome.

Does it work? Are there browsers that support it? If not, is it on a roadmap?

Full disclaimer: I am using keepass2android and it doesn't seem to work. Google has made them remove the accessibility feature that worked and keepass2android claims that they have now implemented Oreo autofill integration, but that doesn't seem to work with chrome.

I've read around that the chrome team was planning on making android autofill work within chrome, but I don't know how trustworthy it all is and/or how old. I am curious if it is even possible to have an app that tells autofill where it's fields are and what it's app name/ URL is... Or whether autofill is a one way system.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that Keepass2Android did the work correctly, it works on Firefox like a dream, but they have not implemented it in Chrome even to this day which is sad. The best I can do is to share the page to Keepass2Android and the app will take me to a keyboard selection page where I can choose the special keyboard and be sent back to chrome to fill my fields.